Performance Issue with Particle Swarm Optimization for VRP
I am a computer science student and working on a Vehicle Routing Problem (VRP) using Particle Swarm Optimization (PSO). I am following the approach outlined in the research paper titled “Particle swarm optimization and two solution representations for solving the capacitated vehicle routing problem” by The Jin Ai and Voratas Kachitvichyanuku.
In my implementation, I have modified the solution representation to include pick-up (.1) and drop-off (.2) points. Given a scenario with 7 customers and 3 vehicles, the initial input is a list of randomly assigned numbers to represent the population (e.g., [[[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]], more particles…]). I have also implemented a function to format the population into a more readable format (e.g., [[{‘1.1’: [datetime.time(0, 15), ‘Depart Location’, PassengerNo, UserID], ‘1.2’: [datetime.time(1, 15), ‘Arrival Location’, PassengerNo, UserID], …}, {…}, {…}]])
Next, I create a customer priority and vehicle priority matrix. The output is as follows: Customer Priority: [[‘2’, ‘3’, ‘4’, ‘7’, ‘5’, ‘1’, ‘6’]]
Vehicle Priority: [[[2, 1, 0], [0, 1, 2], [1, 0, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [1, 0, 2], [0, 1, 2]]]. The customer priority is determined by computing the distance between each customer and the depot, with the nearest customer served first. Each vehicle is then randomly assigned a number based on its latitude and longitude relative to the depot, and the distance between it and the customer is computed to determine the order in which vehicles fetch customers.
When constructing the route, I serve each customer in the priority list, get the vehicle order, and try all possible combinations of customers served by each vehicle. The cost function computes the Euclidean distance between points (e.g., depot to vehicle A to point A back to depot). In the route, the customer is placed in every position, the cost is calculated, and the minimum cost is selected (e.g., [[1,2],[3],[4]], customer 5 will try in the way of [[5,1,2],[1,5,2],[1,2,5]], [[5,3],[3,5]], [[5,4],[4,5]] and select the sequence with least cost.)
However, this approach results in an exponential increase in computation time for a single particle as the number of passengers and vehicles increases. This issue becomes even more pronounced when considering the entire population and multiple iterations to finally display the global best solution.
I am struggling with this concept. Any alternative approaches or ideas to improve the performance of this implementation would be greatly appreciated.
Here's my code:
def construct_routes_v2(customer_priority, vehicle_priority, vehicle_ref_points, capacity, customer_depart_loc_input, customer_arrive_loc_input):
# Loop for each population
for index, customer in enumerate(customer_priority):
    # Vehicle order is retrieving the vehicle priority matrix of the index (From population)
    vehicle_order = vehicle_priority[index]
    # vehicle_order[0] to get the number of vehicles
    pending_compute = list([] for _ in range(len(vehicle_order[0])))
    # format from customer priority: 1 -> 1.1, 1.2
    reformat_customer_priority = []
    for customer_id in customer:
        reformat_customer_priority.append(f'{customer_id}.1')
        reformat_customer_priority.append(f'{customer_id}.2')     
    # Tracking control for each customer to be used in assigning .2 to the vehicle
    customer_vehicle_tracker = []
    for i in reformat_customer_priority:
        if i.endswith('.1'):
            customer_index = int(i.split('.')[0])
            vehicle_customer = vehicle_order[customer_index - 1]
            min_index = None
            min_cost = float('inf')
            min_vehicle_pref = None
            # Loop for each vehicle
            for vehicle_pref in vehicle_customer:
                if len(pending_compute[vehicle_pref]) == 0:
                    pending_compute[vehicle_pref].append(i)
                    cost = compute_cost_v2(pending_compute[vehicle_pref], customer_depart_loc_input, customer_arrive_loc_input, vehicle_ref_points, vehicle_pref)
                    if cost < min_cost:
                        min_cost = cost
                        min_vehicle_pref = vehicle_pref
                        min_index = pending_compute[vehicle_pref]     
                    # Remove the case (element) that is not min cost
                    for j in range(len(pending_compute)):
                        if j != min_vehicle_pref:
                            if i in pending_compute[j]:
                                pending_compute[j].remove(i)    
                else:
                    for j in range(len(pending_compute[vehicle_pref]) + 1):
                        temp_route = pending_compute[vehicle_pref].copy()
                        temp_route.insert(j, i)
                        cost = compute_cost_v2(temp_route, customer_depart_loc_input, customer_arrive_loc_input, vehicle_ref_points, vehicle_pref)
                        if cost < min_cost:
                            min_cost = cost
                            min_vehicle_pref = vehicle_pref
                            min_index = temp_route
            pending_compute[min_vehicle_pref] = min_index
            customer_vehicle_tracker.append([customer_index, min_vehicle_pref])
        else:
            customer_index = int(i.split('.')[0])
            # Customer Vehicle Tracker: [[2, 2]]
            if customer_index == customer_vehicle_tracker[-1][0]:
                customer_vehicle_pref = customer_vehicle_tracker[-1][1]
            # Visit the route that containing the customer only
            vehicle_customer_route = pending_compute[customer_vehicle_pref]
            # Find the position of the corresponding pickup (.1)
            pickup_position = None
            for j, customer_in_route in enumerate(vehicle_customer_route):
                if customer_in_route == f'{customer_index}.1':
                    pickup_position = j
                    break
            min_index = None
            min_cost = float('inf')
            min_vehicle_pref = None
            if pickup_position is not None:
                for j in range(pickup_position + 1, len(vehicle_customer_route) + 1):
                    temp_route = vehicle_customer_route.copy()
                    temp_route.insert(j, i)
                    cost = compute_cost_v2(temp_route, customer_depart_loc_input, customer_arrive_loc_input, vehicle_ref_points, customer_vehicle_pref)
                    if cost < min_cost:
                        min_cost = cost
                        min_vehicle_pref = customer_vehicle_pref
                        min_index = temp_route
            pending_compute[min_vehicle_pref] = min_index   
    # Validate Candidate (Checking constraints)
    pending_compute = validate_candidate_v2(pending_compute, capacity, customer_depart_loc_input, customer_arrive_loc_input, vehicle_ref_points)
    return pending_compute

Clarification: compute_cost_v2 is the function that calculate the Euclidean Distance between each point while validate_candidate function is checking whether the length of the routes is greater than the constraints, pop the last element and reassign to other routes that can satisfy the capacity.

Hi, I have been limited to implement PSO at this moment. If you can help in improving my method, that will be great!

@user24714692 Hi, the expected result should be a list of generated route: [['7.1', '4.1', '4.2', '7.2'], ['3.1', '2.1', '3.2', '1.1', '2.2', '1.2'], ['5.1', '6.1', '5.2', '6.2']]
In case you wish to know how I compute the cost, it's Euclidean Distance between points and points using their lat and lng. It's a close loop calculation, first determining pick-up or drop-off for the customer, then extract their corresponding location (lat and lng), calculate the distance between prev and curr until all of the points has been computed.


Optimizing a VRP using PSO is challenging because of the complexity of the problem and exponential growth in computational time.

There are however ways to optimize it, such as improving the cost function efficiency, multi-threading or parallel processing, caching, local search integration, etc.


Adding local search to PSO

We can consider adding a local search method to the PSO, and technically we would create a hybrid technique:

We pass the routes to the local search and look for finding the best cost and route, based on an O(N ^ 2) method.

You can use other techniques to improve this method to O(N log N), but here for simplicity, we check every pair of routes and compute_cost_v2() to find the best_route:


def local_search(R):
    best_route = R
    best_cost = compute_cost_v2(R)
    for i in range(len(R)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(r)):
            new_route = R[:i] + R[i:j][::-1] + R[j:]
            new_cost = compute_cost_v2(new_route)
            if new_cost < best_cost:
                best_route = new_route
                best_cost = new_cost
    return best_route

Then, we use the above local search method for every particle in the population of PSO:
def pso(population):
    for i, particle in enumerate(population):
        particle = local_search(particle)
        population[i] = particle
    return population


Code
import numpy as np


def compute_cost_v2(
        route,
        customer_depart_loc_input=None,
        customer_arrive_loc_input=None,
        vehicle_ref_points=None,
        vehicle_pref=None):
    customer_indices = [int(customer_id.split('.')[0]) for customer_id in route]
    return np.linalg.norm(np.diff(customer_indices, axis=0))


def validate_candidate_v2(
        pending_compute,
        capacity,
        customer_depart_loc_input=None,
        customer_arrive_loc_input=None,
        vehicle_ref_points=None):
    return pending_compute


def local_search(R):
    best_route = R
    best_cost = compute_cost_v2(R)
    for i in range(len(R)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(r)):
            new_route = R[:i] + R[i:j][::-1] + R[j:]
            new_cost = compute_cost_v2(new_route)
            if new_cost < best_cost:
                best_route = new_route
                best_cost = new_cost
    return best_route


def pso(population):
    for i, particle in enumerate(population):
        particle = local_search(particle)
        population[i] = particle
    return population


def construct_routes_v2(customer_priority,
                        vehicle_priority,
                        vehicle_ref_points,
                        capacity,
                        customer_depart_loc_input,
                        customer_arrive_loc_input):
    for index, customer in enumerate(customer_priority):
        vehicle_order = vehicle_priority[index]
        pending_compute = list([] for _ in range(len(vehicle_order[0])))
        reformat_customer_priority = []
        for customer_id in customer:
            reformat_customer_priority.append(f'{customer_id}.1')
            reformat_customer_priority.append(f'{customer_id}.2')
        customer_vehicle_tracker = []
        for i in reformat_customer_priority:
            if i.endswith('.1'):
                customer_index = int(i.split('.')[0])
                vehicle_customer = vehicle_order[customer_index - 1]
                min_index = None
                min_cost = float('inf')
                min_vehicle_pref = None
                for vehicle_pref in vehicle_customer:
                    if len(pending_compute[vehicle_pref]) == 0:
                        pending_compute[vehicle_pref].append(i)
                        cost = compute_cost_v2(
                            pending_compute[vehicle_pref],
                            customer_depart_loc_input,
                            customer_arrive_loc_input,
                            vehicle_ref_points,
                            vehicle_pref)
                        if cost < min_cost:
                            min_cost = cost
                            min_vehicle_pref = vehicle_pref
                            min_index = pending_compute[vehicle_pref]
                        for j in range(len(pending_compute)):
                            if j != min_vehicle_pref:
                                if i in pending_compute[j]:
                                    pending_compute[j].remove(i)
                    else:
                        for j in range(len(pending_compute[vehicle_pref]) + 1):
                            temp_route = pending_compute[vehicle_pref].copy()
                            temp_route.insert(j, i)
                            cost = compute_cost_v2(temp_route, customer_depart_loc_input,
                                                   customer_arrive_loc_input, vehicle_ref_points, vehicle_pref)
                            if cost < min_cost:
                                min_cost = cost
                                min_vehicle_pref = vehicle_pref
                                min_index = temp_route
                pending_compute[min_vehicle_pref] = min_index
                customer_vehicle_tracker.append([customer_index, min_vehicle_pref])
            else:
                customer_index = int(i.split('.')[0])
                if customer_index == customer_vehicle_tracker[-1][0]:
                    customer_vehicle_pref = customer_vehicle_tracker[-1][1]
                vehicle_customer_route = pending_compute[customer_vehicle_pref]
                pickup_position = None
                for j, customer_in_route in enumerate(vehicle_customer_route):
                    if customer_in_route == f'{customer_index}.1':
                        pickup_position = j
                        break
                min_index = None
                min_cost = float('inf')
                min_vehicle_pref = None
                if pickup_position is not None:
                    for j in range(pickup_position + 1, len(vehicle_customer_route) + 1):
                        temp_route = vehicle_customer_route.copy()
                        temp_route.insert(j, i)
                        cost = compute_cost_v2(temp_route, customer_depart_loc_input,
                                               customer_arrive_loc_input, vehicle_ref_points, customer_vehicle_pref)
                        if cost < min_cost:
                            min_cost = cost
                            min_vehicle_pref = customer_vehicle_pref
                            min_index = temp_route
                pending_compute[min_vehicle_pref] = min_index
    pending_compute = validate_candidate_v2(
        pending_compute, capacity, customer_depart_loc_input, customer_arrive_loc_input, vehicle_ref_points)
    return pending_compute


customer_priority = [['2', '3', '4', '7', '5', '1', '6']]
vehicle_priority = [[[2, 1, 0], [0, 1, 2], [1, 0, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [1, 0, 2], [0, 1, 2]]]
vehicle_ref_points = np.random.rand(3, 2)
capacity = [3, 3, 3]
customer_depart_loc_input, customer_arrive_loc_input = np.random.rand(7, 2), np.random.rand(7, 2)


result = construct_routes_v2(customer_priority,
                             vehicle_priority,
                             vehicle_ref_points,
                             capacity,
                             customer_depart_loc_input,
                             customer_arrive_loc_input)
print(result)



Prints
[
['1.1', '1.2', '2.1', '2.2'], 
['6.1', '6.2', '5.1', '5.2', '3.1', '3.2'], 
['7.1', '7.2', '4.1', '4.2']
]


Hi, it is good to learn about a simpler approach for regenerating the route (similar to GA crossover). However, in my current implementation, I am experiencing performance issues due to the fact that I am assigning each customer to each position in the route for each vehicle (‘Brute Force’) approach, which is causing an increase in computational time. I would like to remain both customer priority and vehicle priority in route construction. Are there other alternatives such as insertion heuristics, saving algorithms, or parallel processing etc? Thank you for your help and guidance!

@RookieTechie Of course, those are all options and you know it, therefore you can implement it. But, before that, first you really need to write your code a bit modular, otherwise it'll be difficult to debug and optimize, just like now. I did try to dive into construct_routes_v2, but it is hard to debug. Note that, you can break it apart and ask multiple questions, to optimize it step by step. Also, you can use improve your data structure choices. Wait, maybe some others might have better answers to your questions.
